# Setting up router when modem doesn't have bridge mode, so that DHCP and Port Forward Happen on Router

Tags: router, wireless-networking

I have a new Wifi router, and for some inane reason, my modem won't allow bridged mode for my ADSL2 connection.

How do I set up my external router, and my current modem/router so that the dedicated router handles all tasks such as DHCP, Access point, port forwarding etc?

The specific questions I have are...

1. Do I set both devices to be on the same IP range, or have them separate? (e.g one on 192.168.0.1 and the other on 192.168.1.1)
2. Do I disable DHCP on the modem if it is on a separate range?
3. How will I set up port forwarding? Is it just a matter of forwarding ports from the modem to the router, and then on to the local location?

Edit: My original modem/router does allow bridge mode for VDSL and Fiber, but just not ADSL2, which is frustrating.

- Modem/Router: Huawei HG630b
- Router: D-Link DIR-880L

Comment: Q: "What is best practice for setting up my external router...?"  A: There are [no best practices](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/197/775).

Comment: OK thanks I didn't know about this. I will reword it.

Comment: we might be able to improve answers to this question if we knew what model and manufacturer router you have. Could you add that information to the question?

Comment: It may seem counter productive to my cause but I left this out so the question would be useful to anyone else. I couldn't find much info on the web about what I imagine is a relatively common configuration question. My carrier supplied modem firmware seems to be pretty locked down and relatively uncommon due to my locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really there is no best practice; the best you can do is choose the lesser evil.

1. Connect with one subnet, as you describe in your question.

   - If it is connected to one common client subnet, DHCP must kept only on one device
   - Set the default gateway to the ADSL device
   - You must configure all firewall, dst-nat (eg. portmap, service publication), UPnP on ADSL.
   - In this scenario You interconnect LANs of Modem and Router.

But if 1. is sufficient, why do you need a separate router?

2. Connect your router's WAN port to LAN port of the ADSL device.

   - In this scenario You need 2 subnets: `ADSL LAN <-(subnet1)-> WAN Router2 LAN <-(subnet2 real LAN)-> PCs`
   - If the ADSL device supports a "DMZ" (map all connection to one internal IP), then you can configure it to IP of Router2's WAN interface. Then you can get inbound connections, and configure dst-nat (eg. portmap, service publication), UPnP on Router2.
3. Exotic scenario. If ADSL router, support PPPoE passtrough or relay feature, You can enable it, connect WAN of the router to LAN of Modem and configure PPPoE on Router.

   - It possible preferred scenario, because it assign external IP directly to Router, but it use relative rare feature.
   - In this scenario, can be hard to manage adsl modem from LAN

Comment: OK thanks for the advice, in scenario 1 above where do I connect, if not WAN of router to LAN of modem? As you mentioned for scenario 2?

Comment: I change reply. In 1 scenario You interconnect LANs of Modem and Router.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying that. Just so I know, what do I miss out on not having bridge mode? Is there a trade off in speed?

Comment: Actually in speed no trade off, except situation where ADSL modem too weak to handle full speed in Router mode.
Main trade off in ability to receive inbound connections. It can limit ability to transfer files in IM, use VoIP, make servers (as Web, FTP, VPN, etc...). Third scenario is completely free from this trade off.

Comment: I use port forwarding, see my question # 3. Can I forward twice? So from modem/router, to router, then from router to local host?

Comment: Of course You can forward multiple times. Just not mess with IPs and ports. But double forward is double work to configure each port, so if avialable, I recommend use DMZ IP on ADSL. It must forward all ports and all protocols to router, and You make fine tune at one place, at router.

Comment: Excellent. I have DMZ. Will try soon and let you know.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me (port forwarding included). Thanks for taking time to help.